# Ajax not working in firefox without alert

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, firefox

```
function processAjaxStateChangeForRowAdd() {
    alert(0);
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete
        if (req.status == 200) { // OK response
            processForRowAdd(req.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("Problem: " + req.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working fine for IE, Safari and Firefox, but if I remove the `alert`, then the code will not work in Firefox, though it still works in IE and Safari.

Can anybody give me suggestion why it not working in Firefox without alert?

---

**EDIT:** Code that adds a row:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest && browserVersion.indexOf("Microsoft") == -1 ) {
    // code for Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    req = new XMLHttpRequest("");
    if (req) {
        ajaxProcessed = false;
        req.onreadystatechange = processAjaxStateChangeForRowAdd;
        req.open("POST", url, true);
        req.send();
        // alert("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does it `alert`? Oh, you mean the first one. You did attach this function as a callback handler to your `XMLHttpRequest`, didn't you?

Comment: Like Marcel said...  Are you setting this function as your callback?  req.onreadystatechange = processAjaxStateChangeForRowAdd;

Answer (score 3):

The `alert` is blocking. What this means is that your script is temporarily suspended (even if it's for a few milliseconds). During this time, your AJAX request completes and your `req` object is being set. You can add a delay (using setTimeout) to your callback to verify this.

I would suggest you post more of your script so that we can help you set up your callback properly. Alternatively, use a library such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to set up AJAX calls in a cross-browser manner easily.

---

**EDIT:** You need to either declare `req` as a global variable, or use an anonymous function. The following code demonstrates the first method (using a global variable):

```
var req;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = processAjaxStateChangeForRowAdd;
        req.open("POST", url, true);
        req.send();
    }
}

function processAjaxStateChangeForRowAdd() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete
        if (req.status == 200) { // OK response
            processForRowAdd(req.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("Problem: " + req.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (window.XMLHttpRequest && browserVersion.indexOf("Microsoft") == -1 )
       {
       // code for Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
        req = new XMLHttpRequest("");
        
             
       
             if (req) {
                    ajaxProcessed=false;
                    req.onreadystatechange = processAjaxStateChangeForRowAdd;
                    req.open("POST", url, true);
                    req.send();
                   // alert("1");
                  
              }
          
       }

Comment: @Asit: Oh please, don't post code in comments; edit your question instead (by pressing the 'edit' link near the bottom of your question).

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getHttp()
    {
       var xmlhttp;
      try
      {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        try
        {
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefiend')
            {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
        }
    }
     return xmlhttp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
 if (request.readyState == 4) {
   if (request.status == 200) {
     var response = request.responseText;
   } else
     alert("status: " + request.status);
 }
```

Comment: function processForRowAdd(responseText ){
   
                 
                  
                  if(responseText!=null || responseText.length!=0){
                 
                    document.getElementById(targetElementId).value = responseText;
                  }
                    
                  ajaxProcessed=true;
      }

Comment: if (window.XMLHttpRequest && browserVersion.indexOf("Microsoft") == -1 )
       {
       // code for Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
        req = new XMLHttpRequest("");
        
             
       
             if (req) {
                    ajaxProcessed=false;
                    req.onreadystatechange = processAjaxStateChangeForRowAdd;
                    req.open("POST", url, true);
                    req.send();
                   // alert("1");
                  
              }
          
       }

Answer (score 0):

You should also check for the readyState , the following code might help

```
req.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            processForRowAdd(req.responseText)
        }
}
```

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) for the different values of readyState

Comment: That's the same condition he uses. And please don't recommend W3Schools, see http://w3fools.com for the reason why.